# Android ExpandableListView with buttons not working

Tags: android

I have implemented expandable list view in my application.in my xml,i have some buttons in below of the expandable list view.so when i run my application expandable list view working fine,but my buttons below that list are not working.nothing happening when i click on my buttons,those buttons are not related to expand list view. i set all child views of list to focusable false also.but my button clicks not working..any one help me please?
here is my code,

> ```
> <include
>     android:id="@+id/headerID"
>     layout="@layout/ds_header" />
>
> <include layout="@layout/postadeal_menufooter" />
>
> <LinearLayout
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_below="@+id/headerID" >
>
>     <ExpandableListView
>         android:id="@+id/postadeal_ExpandListID"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="500dp"
>         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>         android:layout_centerVertical="true" >
>     </ExpandableListView>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

Here "postadeal_menufooter" layout contains my buttons,which is below my expandable list view

Answer (score 0):

How are you setting up your xml layout? Do you have them in a RelativeLayout? Make sure that your ExpandableListview is not "on top" of your buttons, otherwise your clicks would be intercepted before it has the chance to propagate to the associated buttons. Also, if you overrode onTouchListeners, check to not intercept clicks that are meant for the buttons. Without any code from you it's rather hard to go further into specifics. Hope this helps.

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/headerID"
    layout="@layout/ds_header" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/headerID" >

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/postadeal_ExpandListID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" >
    </ExpandableListView>
</LinearLayout>

<include layout="@layout/postadeal_menufooter" />
```

Comment: hi donkey,i posted my code.please check it once,when i remove the expandablelistview code the buttons working fine.but when i include that,then the buttons are not working

Comment: try to include the footer after your expandable list xml element. I still can't see if you're using a RelativeLayout as the container for these elements, but assuming that you are using RelativeLayout, the "z-order" of these elements is defined from top to bottom. So in other words your expandable list linearlayout is actually on top of everything since it's the last element to be defined. Try moving the include menu-footer definition to below the linearlayout. I have edited my answer to reflect this. Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Add your footer after the listview.